# How to replace only the last occurrence in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Having a file containing repeated commented lines like:

```
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath"
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath"
```

I want to add a line only after the last occurrence resulting in

```
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath"
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath"
```

To do so I'm using this command:

```
sed -i 's:^\(.*ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/.*\):\1 \nScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath":' file
```

But this results in adding my line after each occurence like:

```
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath"
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath"
```

How can I tell sed to replace only the last occurence?

If there's no way to solve it using sed (as said in comments), please provide alternatives reaching the same result, thanks.

The repeated lines can be separated and with other lines between them like

```
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath"
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath"

# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "another-path"
ScriptAlias /foo/ "just-jump"
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "that's the last"
```

Comment: this is not a job for sed.  Perhaps awk, but I would do it in Python or Perl.

Comment: @MK.Ok .. I was asking for sed because I was using it. If there's no way to solve it using sed, any other method is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you can do it with sed, it's just not ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [tac](http://man.cx/tac) so you print your new line the *first* time you see the pattern:

```
tac file | awk '/ScriptAlias/ && ! seen {print "new line"; seen=1} {print}' | tac
```

Comment: I personally find this an excellent idea and it's still easy to read. I personalized it a little bit and added the ability to write directly to the file, (is there a way to use your solution with interactive -i ?). My command finally is `tac $file | awk '/ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\// && ! seen {print "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ \"mypath\""; seen=1} {print}' | tac > "/var/lock/${file}" && mv "/var/lock/${file}" "${file}"`

Comment: Cannot write to the input file directly. You have to use a temp file (as you did). That's what `sed -i` does in the background

Answer (score 1):

alternative with awk:

```
awk '/ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\//{x=NR} {a[NR]=$0;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(i==x+1)print "$$$here comes new line$$$"; print a[i];}}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath"
fooo
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath"
bar
"|awk '/ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\//{x=NR} {a[NR]=$0;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(i==x+1)print "$$$here comes new line$$$"; print a[i];}}'
```

output:

```
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ somepath
fooo
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ otherpath
$$$here comes new line$$$
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -r temp | awk '{line="yourline"}{if($0~/ScriptAlias/&&last==0){print line"\n"$0;last=1}else print}' | tail -r
```

tested below:

```
krithika.337> cat temp
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath" 
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
# ndmxriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
# bdjiptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
krithika.338> tail -r temp | awk '{line="yourline"}{if($0~/ScriptAlias/&&last==0){print line"\n"$0;last=1}else print}' | tail -r
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "somepath" 
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
# ndmxriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
yourline
# bdjiptAlias /cgi-bin/ "otherpath" 
krithika.339>
```

Comment: GNU tail (from coreutils) doesn't have `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

It is a task for the editor.

```
ex input_file << "DONE"
/ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\/ "otherpath"
a
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath"
.
:1
/ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\/ "another-path"
a
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "just-jump"
.
:x
DONE
```

In last occurence mode.

```
ex input_file << "DONE"
$
?ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\/ "otherpath"
a
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "mypath"
.
$
?ScriptAlias \/cgi-bin\/ "another-path"
a
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "just-jump"
.
:x
DONE
```