# Reverse file using tac and sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I have a usecase where I need to search and replace the last occurrence of a string in a file and write the changes back to the file. The case below is a simplified version of that usecase:

I'm attempting to reverse the file, make some changes reverse it back again and write to the file. I've tried the following snippet for this:

```
tac test | sed s/a/b/ | sed -i '1!G;h;$!d' test
```

test is a text file with contents:

```
a
1 
2 
3
4
5
```

I was expecting this command to make no changes to the order of the file, but it has actually reversed the contents to:

```
5
4
3
2
1
b
```

How can i make the substitution as well as retain the order of the file?

Comment: See: [Bash: how to use sed to replace only the last occurence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10106292/3776858) or https://www.google.com/#q=bash+replace+last+occurrence+in+file

Comment: The difference here is I need to write back to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to user `grep` to get the number of the last line that contains the text you want to change, then use `sed` to change that line:

```
$ linno=$( grep -n 'abc' <file> | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1 )

$ sed -i "${linno}s/abc/def/" <file>
```

Comment: you can also use sed's `=` command.. to get only line number of match... for ex: `seq 20 | sed -n '/4/=' | tail -1`

Comment: I like it!  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4):

You can `tac` your file, apply substitution on first occurrence of desired pattern, `tac` again and `tee` result to a temporary file before you rename it with the original name:

```
tac file | sed '0,/a/{s//b/}' | tac > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to `cat test | rev | sed -i '1!G;h;$!d' | rev`

Or you can use only `sed` coomand:
For example you want to replace `ABC` on `DEF`:

You need to add 'g' to the end of your sed:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/g'
```

This tells sed to replace every occurrence of your regex ("globally") instead of only the first occurrence.

You should also add a `$`, if you want to ensure that it is replacing the last occurrence of ABC on the line:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC$/\1DEF/g'
```

**EDIT**

Or simply add another `| tac` to your command:
`tac test | sed s/a/b/ | sed -i '1!G;h;$!d' | tac`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this in a single command using `awk`.

First input file:

```
cat file
a
1
2
3
4
a
5
```

Now this awk command:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0} END{p=i; while(i--) if (sub(/a/, "b", a[i])) break;
      for(i=0; i<p; i++) print a[i]}' file
a
1
2
3
4
b
5
```

To save output back into original file use:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0} END{p=i; while(i--) if (sub(/a/, "b", a[i])) break;
for(i=0; i<p; i++) print a[i]}' file >> $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp f
```

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. First a test file:

```
$ cat file
a
1
a
2
a
```

and solution:

```
$ awk '
$0=="a" && NR>1 {             # when we meet "a"
    print b; b=""             # output and clear buffer b
}
{
    b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0     # gether the buffer
}
END {                         # in the end
    sub(/^a/,"b",b)           # replace the leading "a" in buffer b with "b"
    print b                   # output buffer 
}' file
a
1
a
2
b
```

Writing back the happens by redirecting the output to a temp file which replaces the original file (`awk ... file > tmp && mv tmp file`) or if you are using GNU awk v. 4.1.0+ you can use inplace edit (`awk -i inplace ...`).